# how to display google line chart such that chart display different line in line chart in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have some same `supplier_name` stored in database.I want different line for each `supplier_name` but repeated `supplier_name` should not form differnt line in line chart to display in asp.net mvc.

```
public class AuctionChart
{

public int ID { get; set; }

public string Supplier_Name { get; set; }

public int Rate { get; set; }

}
```

following is the line chart which i have done but i dont want like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rU8vc.png

Thank u in advance